# Angularjs updates model fail after http call

Tags: angularjs

I have a group of accounts like `[{username: xxx, password: xxx} , ....]`, then I print them to page like below,

```
<tr ng-repeat = 'account in accounts'>
   <td>{{account.username}}<td>
   <td>{{account.password}}<td>
   <td><button ng-click='ResetPassword(account)'>Reset</button></td>
</tr>
```

The `ResetPassword()` func,

```
$scope.ResetPassword = function(account){
        $http.post('/reset/password/'+account.username).success(function(rAccount){

            account = rAccount; //account & rAccount have the same structure.
         }
    });
};
```

**The problem is** if I override `account=rAccount`, the password UI never been updated, unless I set the attribute manually like `account.password = rAccount.password`, see this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/20039/)

So, why it doesn't work via obj overriding? then how to fix it? my `account` is far more complex than this example, it's not a good practice to update one by one I think, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work mainly because,  angularjs adds a $$hashKey property to objects in collections that are being used with ng-repeat.

$$hashkey is a auto generated key which angular assigns to array,collection passed in ng-repeat directive. Angular uses it to keep track of any changes made to array and update dom accordingly.

So in your case account and rAccount doesn't have the same structure. thats why it works for **angular.extend** as @anik-islam-abhi suggested. You can also use

> angular.copy(source,[destination]);

Like

```
 angular.copy(rAccount,account);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/20042/

Answer (score 1):

Use [**angular.extend**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend)

> angular.extend(dst, src);

Like this

```
angular.extend(account, rAccount);
```

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/HB7LU/20040/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

`account = rAccount` does not work. You have to update `$scope.accounts` value

See http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/20043/